# Are rogue droids a common occurrence?

Tags: star-wars, droids

By rogue I mean droids who are self-reliant, that don't have (or at least don't obey) an owner (be it a specific organic or institution). Known examples are the bounty hunter droids 4-LOM and the IG-88 droids- are there many others?

Comment: Is it possible that the bounty hunter droids mentioned actually do have an owner? Someone could have built those droids for bounty hunting, and when said droids get their bounty, they return to their owner and give the owner the bounty.

Comment: @Gooseman- The SW Essential Guide to Droids describes their pasts in detail, saying otherwise. Also the short story collection Tales of the Bounty Hunters depicts the IG droids wiping out the organics who built them and striking out on their own (there might have been a story on 4-LOM too, but I'd have to reread it to be sure).

Comment: @Nu'Daq - hopefully, what I listed in my answer qualifies as "common" enough for your intent? :)

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your scope and definition of "Rogue", they are a common occurence by sheer numbers (but less common by individual types/instances).

- Yuuzhan Vong galaxy apparently had 2 whole **civilizations** of rogue droids:  [Silentium](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Silentium) and the [Abominor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Abominor).

  They are covered in EU/Legends canon (multiple sources listed in the linked Wiki articles, mostly assorted Droid related titles)

  - Since Silentium settled in TGFFA eventually, that's even true of the main Star Wars Galaxy.
- There was a whole army of rogue droids in *Clone Wars*: [HELIOS-3D's droid army](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/HELIOS-3D's_droid_army) *(src: The Clone Wars: Hunting the Hunters (Part III))*. ***DISNEY CANON!***
- [Great Droid Revolution/Great Droid Revolt](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Great_Droid_Revolution) of 4015 BBY had obviously a lot of rogue droids. (multiple EU/Legends sources on Wikia)
- [Bacura Droid Uprising in 97 BBY](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Droid_Uprising) is borderline, in that it was caused by a virus. So one can argue it wasn't true rogue droids
- [400100500260026](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/400100500260026) was an independent territory in the Gordian Reach consisting of **sixteen planets ruled by G0-T0 droids** who seceded from Old Republic in 3946 BBY.
- [Second great droid revolution](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Second_Great_Droid_Revolution) in 10BBY

  The cyborg Archa Sabis uploaded a virus into the droid population which caused several police cruisers and EVS Construction droids to rebel against their sentient masters.
- [Droid community](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Uffel_droid_community) colonized the moon Uffel in the Cularin system.
- Individual rogue droids were common enough, apparently, that many were included in SW EU canon, in large numbers.

  - [EV-9D9](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/EV-9D9/Legends) (she is actually ***G/Disney-canon***, being the droid which tortures other droids in ROTJ in Jabba's palace, but her rogue nature - she was apparently just hiding out in Jabba's palace - is from EU/Legends).
  - [G0-T0-Telerath](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/G0-T0-Telerath)
  - [Mark VII](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mark_VII_experimental_prototype_assassin_droid)
  - [Runaway B1 droid](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lone_battle_droid)
  - [HG-211](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/HG-211)
  - [LN-73](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/LN-73)
  - [HK-51 series assassin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/HK-51_series_assassin_droid)
  - [IG-88 (A-D)](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/IG-88's_Droid_Army)
  - [Rogue RT-16](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/RT-16_Patrol_Droid)
  - [I-5YQ](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/I-5YQ)
  - Rogue [GRZ-6B wrecker droid](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/GRZ-6B_wrecker_droid) fought by Zed
  - [Rodent](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rodent_%28droid%29) was a rogue MSE-series mouse droid
  - [MI-726](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/MI-726)
  - [C-3PX](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/C-3PX)
  - [HK-01](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/HK-01) (instigator of Great Droid Revolution mentioned above)
  - [GSAD-43](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/GSAD-43)
  - [B-1D4](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/B-1D4)
  - [8t88](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/8t88)
  - Some of [Colicoid Infiltrator-series droids](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Colicoid_Infiltrator-series_droid) went rogue
  - Some [T-41 battle droids](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/T-41_Battle_Droid) went rogue
  - An unnamed rogue labor droid that Lando encountered in *Crisis on Cloud City*
  - Rogue [DLC-13 mining droid](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/DLC-13_mining_droid/Legends)
  - "The Doctor", aka [Z2-1B](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Z2-1B)
  - [Annamar experimental battle droids](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Annamar_experimental_battle_droid) that went rogue
  - Droids that took over [Okara Droid Company](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Okara_Droid_Company) during Sith war.
  - [Skippy the Jedi Droid](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Skippy_the_Jedi_Droid). No, not kidding. (hat/tip: @Thunderforge's answer, with his permission, for completeness)
  - [Guri](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Guri), Prince Xizor's onetime bodyguard. (same h/tip)
  - And, for grand finale, there was a **made up** "rogue" droid [10-4TO](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/10-4TO), aka "Bug Eyes". Except it was a trap by Vader, not a real rogueness.

Comment: I skipped Guri and Skippy, because I adore Guri and mind-bleached myself of Skippy. Well, and because someone else mentioned them earlier in another answer.

Comment: I'm fine with you including those two, since your answer is already far more complete than mine. But please overcome your mind bleach and include Skippy :-)

Answer (score 1):

> I mean droids who are self-reliant, that don't have (or at least don't obey) an owner (be it a specific organic or institution)

Well, there's one very important droid who fits that description:

[image: R2-D2]

R2-D2 chose to run away to run away from his owner, Luke Skywalker, and seek out Obi-Wan Kenobi. Of course, it needed its restraining bolt removed in order for this to happen. Also, Luke later gifted R2 to Jabba the Hutt, yet the droid helped Luke escape, directly leading to the downfall of Jabba.

There are a number of examples, especially in Legends continuity, where droids start doing strange things when they do not have a restraining bolt and are left to their own devices. Aside from the ones you already mentioned, there are droids such as:

- The [rogue assassin droid](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mark_VII_experimental_prototype_assassin_droid) in the Korriban tombs (*Knights of the Old Republic*)

  - Ran away from its masters and killed those who went after it
- [T3-M4](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/T3-M4) (especially in *Knights of the Old Republic II*)

  - Made a plan to seek out The Exile and those who would help them
- [Guri](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Guri) (*Shadows of the Empire*)

  - With her master Prince Xizor dead, she traveled the galaxy on her own
- [Skippy the Jedi Droid](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Skippy_the_Jedi_Droid) (*Star Wars Tales* —non-canon— decided to detonate himself in order to get Luke to pick R2-D2)

Note that several of these droids are not following orders, but still act out of a sense of loyalty to a previous master, despite no longer previously being owned by them.

This is why memory wipes are commonly given to droids. Without regular memory wipes, they tend to start showing odd behaviors like this. While a restraining bolt can prevent them from doing anything "rogue", they can still talk back or otherwise make things unpleasant.

Comment: R2D2 had an owner - Princess Leia - who he was obeying.

Comment: @DVK He was purchased by Luke, making him the new owner. R2 surely was aware of that. Following the instructions of a previous owner seems to me like an example of going rogue.

Comment: He was stolen goods. Purchase of stolen goods is **invalid**, in most sane jurisdictions.

Comment: @DVK Fair enough, although Luke didn't know that (pretty sure Luke wonders if they are stolen in the novelization). R2 would know he was stolen though. It would be an interesting question for the future to know if a droid would consider themselves to have a new master if they are stolen.

Comment: @DVK Just remembered that Luke gifted R2 to Jabba, yet R2 still worked against its new owner. So there is another instance of him betraying his owner. Still, there is a future question about when a droid considers itself belonging to a new owner.

Comment: R2D2 was in on the fact that it wasn't a real gift (unlike C-3PO). Nice try though. Also, the question explicitly defines "Rogue" as "working for itself" - in both instances, the droid is NOT working for itself, but for Leia and Luke respectively, even regardless of the ownerhship points I raised.

Comment: I still submit that R2 was operating under its own volition, just out of loyalty to previous owners. Anyway, I tried to move this to chat but the site said you weren't able to right now. Let's just agree to disagree for the time being.